# \pagebreak and \newpage problem (Miktex 2.9; Texworks 5.12.4)

Tags: page-breaking

I tried to write both command and none of them worked. If the text longer than 1 page and I wrote one of them into the text, the process isn't running. If I didn't write it into the text, it is running perfectly. Can somebody help me what is the problem?

Comment: if you want someone to debug an error in your code, you need to show some code. Make a small complete document that has a `\pagebreak` that isn't forcing a page break, then someone can explain why it is not working in that case.

Comment: perhaps `\pagebreak` has been redefined to do nothing. Perhaps your text is in an unbreakable box such as a `minipage` , perhaps there is some conditional code and the `\pagebreak` is not executed at all, it is impossible to guess.